# Login in angular 2

Tags: http, angular

I am an intern front-end developr, trying to make my way trough Angular 2. This project involves a simple login screen which I cannot get to work. I have tried various solutions to the problem but it simply does not work.
I keep on getting errors that I connot seem to get rid of. This time it's "Error during evaluation of 'submit'".
"Cannot read property 'post' of undefined. I worked on this problem for days and I am getting nowhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

I have a LoginService, a LoginComponent and a login.html

login.html:

```
<div id="login-container" class="center-block">
<form role="form" (submit)="login($event, username.value, password.value)">
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" 
        #username class="form-control" 
        id="username" 
        placeholder="Gebruikersnaam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password"
        #password class="form-control" 
        id="password" placeholder="Paswoord">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="login-remember">
        <button type="submit" id="btn-login"
        class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

The loginComponent:

```
import { Component, View, Inject } from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from 'angular2/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { Http, Headers, contentHeaders } from 'angular2/http';
import {UserVM} from '../../interfaces/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './app/templates/login.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [Http]

})
export class LoginCmp {
      login(event, username, password) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sessions/create', body, { headers: contentHeaders })
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          localStorage.setItem('jwt', response.json().id_token);
          this.router.parent.navigateByUrl('/actuals');
        },
        error => {
          alert(error.text());
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
  }
}
```

The loginService:

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, Http} from 'angular2/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { contentHeaders } from '../common/headers';


export class LoginService {

  constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
  }

  login(event, username, password) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sessions/create', body, { headers: contentHeaders })
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          localStorage.setItem('jwt', response.json().id_token);
          this.router.parent.navigateByUrl('/actuals');
        },
        error => {
          alert(error.text());
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject the `http` instance into your `LoginCmp` component:

```
export class LoginCmp {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }
}
```

This will fix your error: "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined.".

I see that you implement a service for the login processing, you could leverage it:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ LoginService ]
})
export class LoginCmp {
  constructor(private loginService:LoginService) {
  }

  login() {
    this.loginService.login(this.username, this.password);
  }
}
```

One last comment. You should use `[(ngModel)]` to get values of username and password instead of local variables because they anre't made for this...

Comment: Thierry, I have tried the first 2 (http and refactoring the loginComponent. I get a different error, so that's progress right? The following error I get is this: EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend! (LoginCmp -> Http -> ConnectionBackend)

Comment: You need to set all the providers regarding http. Something like that `providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]`. Not only the `Http` one...